# find command in bash shell and the -name option doubts

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, find

What is the difference between the two below:

```
find . -type f -name \*.bmp
find . -type f -name *.bmp
```

I have tested,they both return the same result,so is there anything different `_deep inside_`?

---

Added from the [removed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5684070/1983854):

So it is to avoid the shell expansion for the special ***** character,solely pass * as a argument to the find command and let it process it.

But on my machine,they are all good, both return the bmp files in and below the current directory,to name a few,the result is like below,some are omitted for brevity

```
./images/building_color.bmp
./images/building_gray.bmp
./images/car_gray.bmp
./images/temple_color.bmp
./images/boat_gray.bmp
./images/tools_gray.bmp
./images/temple_gray.bmp
./images/tools_color.bmp
./images/car_color.bmp
./images/boat_color.bmp
```

system info:

GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Linux sysabod-laptop 2.6.32-30-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 21:30:21 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: better to run it as `find . -type f -name '*.bmp' to avoid shell expansion and errors on directories.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how they're different: the first one always works, and the second one doesn't.

As for why: in bash, shell globs (wildcard patterns including * or ?) are expanded by the shell into all files matching the glob.  However, if no such files exist, the pattern is left alone.

So, if you're in a directory with no `bmp` files, the commands work the same way, because the first is escaped and bash fails to find any files matching in the second case.

If you ran it from a directory containing only one such file, say `foo.bmp`, the first would find all `bmp` files in the subtree, while the second would find all files named `foo.bmp` only.  If run in a directory with multiple `bmp` files, I believe you'll get an error because `find` doesn't know what to do with all the filenames.

Comment: Thanks for the "However, if no such files exist, the pattern is left alone." bit!

Answer (score 3):

When you escape the asterisk (`\*`) the asterisk itself is passed as argument to the `find` command and will be evaluated by `find`. If you don't escape the asterisk (`*`) already the shell evaluates it and expands it to the file names matching the pattern.

Fore example consider following directory structure:

```
./a.txt
./b.bmp
./c.bmp
./dir/d.doc
./dir/e.bmp
```

When you execute

```
find . -type f -name *.bmp
```

the shell expands `*.bmp` to `b.bmp c.bmp`. I.e. the command that is actually executed will be:

```
find . -type f -name b.bmp c.bmp
```

which will find `b.bmp` and `c.bmp` but not `dir/e.bmp`.

When you execute

```
find . -type f -name \*.bmp
```

`*.bmp` is passed directly as it is to `find`. `find` will recurse through the current directory (`.`) and all its subdirectories (in the example only `dir`) and will find all files in those directories matching the pattern. The result will be: `b.bmp`, `c.bmp` and also `dir/e.bmp`.

Comment: @cd1,@bmk

so it is to avoid the shell expansion for the special * character,solely pass * as a argument to the find command and let it process it.

But on my machine,they are all good, both return the bmp files in and below the current directory,to name a few,the result is like below,some are omitted for brevity

./images/building_color.bmp
./images/building_gray.bmp
./images/car_gray.bmp
./images/temple_color.bmp
./images/boat_gray.bmp
./images/tools_gray.bmp
./images/temple_gray.bmp
./images/tools_color.bmp
./images/car_color.bmp
./images/boat_color.bmp

Answer (score 2):

The first command:

```
find . -type f -name \*.bmp
```

passes an asterisk to the `find` command, and that tells it to find *all the files in and below the current directory ending with .bmp*.

The second command:

```
find . -type f -name *.bmp
```

may be resolved by the shell to, for example:

```
find . -type f -name image1.bmp image2.bmp image3.bmp
```

(that would be the bmp files in the current directory only)

and `find` would only list them, *not the bmp files in other directories below the current one*.