# find file with "find" just giving one result

Tags: bash, find

I try to find a file by using the command find but i really don't see what i am doing wrong:

```
find . -name "rand*"
```

So I want to search from the current directory in all subdirectories, and the name is not exactly specified but has to start with rand.

Well `find` gives me only one hit after which it just stops calculating, nothing happens any more, and I am sure there are more hits for this search than one. So really don't know how to change the command that I get all of the hits

Comment: Weird, because the syntax is fine. What if you manually indicate how deep you want `find` to look? `find . -maxdepth 10 -name "rand*"`, for example.

Comment: I have a feeling that this problem is going to be very difficult to reproduce. Perhaps it would be helpful to show the output of `ls -l` in the root of your search and also in a subdirectory containing a file that you are expecting to find.

Comment: How about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672577/find-command-in-bash-shell-and-the-name-option-doubts) ?

Comment: execute `ls -lR . | grep -i rand` to see all files having 'rand' (case insensitive) in their name (at the beginning or not) and see if that gives an idea as to why they are not captured by `find`. Also, can use `find . -iname "rand*"` to be case insensitive.

Comment: hmm ok, I tried the first suggestion with maxdepth and this is changing the behaviour and it retrieves all of the hits, strange but now it works with this command

Comment: And the suggested link is not the same case, it has to do with the syntax of the call